# How to pre-select a form radio item with Symfony 2?

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox, radio-button

I'm working on a language choice form:

```
    $currentLocale = "en_US"; // This is indeed sent to the formType

    $langs = array(
        'fr_FR' => 'fr',
        'en_US' => 'en'
        );

    $builder->add('language', 'language', array(
        'choices' => $langs,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'label' => false,
    ));
```

The HTML code looks like this (simplified):

```
<div id="languageForm_language">
    <input type="radio" value="fr_FR">
    <input type="radio" value="en_US">
</div>
```

How could I get the second item pre-selected, according to the `$currentLocale` value ?

Comment: Is this form bound to a data object as well, or is it a 'plain' form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `$langs` array you can specify key value pairs like this:

```
array(
  0 => 'value1',
  1 => 'value2'
)
```

Now, e.g. you want to preselect `value2`, you can set the `data` attribute to the key from `value2`:

```
$builder->add('language', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $langs,
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'label' => false,

    'data' => 1
));
```

According to this, you can set your `data` attribute to your `$currentLocale` variable to preselect it. **Your code should look like this:**

```
$currentLocale = "en_US"; // This is indeed sent to the formType

$langs = array(
    'fr_FR' => 'fr',
    'en_US' => 'en'
);

$builder->add('language', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $langs,
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'label' => false,
    'data' => $currentLocale
));
```

**Note:** the second parameter from the `add()` method should be `choice` not `language`.

Comment: I just tried it, there was a mistake in the second parameter, 'languante' should be 'choice', because it's a choice field. This code works for me

Comment: I understand my code should work. However, it still does not for me... I guess I miss something somewhere...

Comment: you changed the second parameter to `choice?` Edited my answer, added the code that works for me

Comment: This is precisely what I am looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, if there are three options in choices i.e. 0,1 and 2 and I preselect with 'data' => 1, then I cannot select 2 anymore BUT I can select 0. It ignores everything bigger than the default. WHY?!

Answer (score 5):

If the form is used with a model object, just set the language on the object itself before passing it to the form:

```php
$object->setLanguage($currentLocale);
$form = $this->createForm('some_form_type', $object);
```

Otherwise, set the [`data` option](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html#data) to the default language key:

```php
$builder->add('language', 'language', array(
    'choices' => $langs,
    'data'    => $currentLocale,
    // ...
));
```