# How to preselect the radiobutton when 'data' is entity

Tags: symfony, entity

Normally,form shows the select code though,
I have two tables which has Many-to-one relation.

for example

MainTable

```
ID | name |job
1  | Mr.A |1
2  | Mr.D |1
3  | Mr.C |3
```

jobTable

```
ID | name    
1  | doctor
2  | engineer
3  | teacher
```

then ,I am making the form to input Maintable,normally
symfony uses select box for this kind of choice,but I use radio button like this.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($mainTable)
->add('job','entity',array(
        'class' => 'AcmeTopBundle:jobTable','expanded' => true))
```

Then I would like to preselect the one button.

There I found hint.

[How to pre-select a form radio item with Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135067/how-to-pre-select-a-form-radio-item-with-symfony-2)

it says to use

'data' => 1

But my choices is jobTable entity.

How can I put the jobtable entity?

'data' => ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the entity record it self as data. So, from a Controller :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

// If you want to preselect record with ID #1
$preselectedData = $em->getReference('AcmeTopBundle:jobTable', 1);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($mainTable)
             ->add(
                 'job','entity',array(
                    'class' => 'AcmeTopBundle:jobTable','expanded' => true,
                    'data' => $preselectedData
                 )
             )
             // ...
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to set the default value in your `entity/value object`. The form component take care of them and preselect it.